# Gsuite custom domain, already setup SPF, DKIM, DMARC, and yet email still going to junk

Tags: email

Im starting a new business, so rather than use my current @hotmail.com email I tried my hand at a professional looking email account. I registered a .com domain and I signed up for Gsuite. I then setup SPF, DKIM, and DMARC correctly. I know it was setup correctly as I ran the google mxsetup tool and it showed no issues.

My email that I send using mail.google.com ends up in the junk folder of hotmail users. My domain is not blacklisted and Im not sending any links or attachments in my email.
Is there anything else I can do? Im just a hobbyist. Do I need to connect my gsuite account to sendgrid to ensure my emails inboxed properly?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's hard to be able to tell what the issue is without knowing your domain and setup. However, you may be able to figure out what's going wrong with the [mxtoolbox website](https://mxtoolbox.com/).